# Why does my Ionic app ask for camera permission? And how do I turn it off?

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, ionic-framework

I am currently developing an application with Ionic, and as I was looking on my phone i noticed that it requires permission for using the camera.

I do not know why it asks for the camera permission. I have gone through my list of plugins and did not see any `android.permission.CAMERA` in the plugin.xml's.

Once i searched the whole project for `android.permission.CAMERA` I did found results in the AndroidManifest.xml of the android-sdk which is sitting in the `platform` folder. I don't know why it asks for this or if this is something that should happen because it is a requirement for the sdk. Howerver I don't use the camera in my app, so I would like to turn this permission off.

Any idea how i would accomplish this?

My list of plugins :

```
com.joandilee.imeiplugin 0.1 "IMEI Plugin"
com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk 3.1.21 "PayPalMobile"
com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.5.5 "Native Page Transitions"
com.telerik.plugins.wkwebview 0.6.7 "WKWebView Polyfill"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.2.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 1.4.0 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.0.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-webserver 1.0.3 "CordovaWebServer"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.8 "Keyboard"
```

AndroidManifest.xml locations in which i found the permission :

`platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/io.card/android-sdk/5.3.0`
`platforms/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/io.card/android-sdk/5.3.0/aapt`
`platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those io.card locations belongs to PayPalMobile plugin which you are using. If you search for "camera" in [PayPalPlugin repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin) you can see plugin tries to use camera in some features therefore it asks for permission to camera.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much, i could not find it myself, but because of you i now know that PayPalPlugin allows users to take photo's of creditcards.

I will mark your answer as the correct one.